# Android search location by name, return relevant location with coordinates

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

Am looking for a way to implement location search in android. I want when user enters location name, result to be relevant depending on user location or user country. When user types something like "KI", to return at least 10 results of location within that country. I would also like to get the coordinates so as to display them on the map if need be. Is there anyway to achieve this? Did not find any helpful solution online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). An example of a request to get addresses in Great Britain:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=high+st+hasting&components=country:GB&key=YOUR_API_KEY.

The response contains the "bounds" object, which you can use to move the map camera:

```
"bounds" : {
  "northeast": {
    "lat": 50.8601041,
    "lng": 0.5957329
  },
  "southwest": {
    "lat": 50.8559061,
    "lng": 0.5906163
  }
}
```

Comment: Geocoding returns null, let me try second the one from url. am coming back

Comment: Url is working fine but for every search, json array is returning one item. When i search like "MU" it's returning only one item. Is there any way to get several results from keyword

Comment: You can use Google Place Autocomplete API: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete to get place predictions.

Comment: Predictions does not seem to provide latitude and longitude

Comment: Using your two methods I have figured out how to achieve my desired solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use an android [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class to get location from position or location name. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) you can find more docs about this.